# Klein's invariant and negative discriminant

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Let $J = J(\tau)$ be Klein's invariant and let $0 < k < 1$ be the elliptic modulus. It is known that
$$J = \frac{4}{27} \frac{(1 - \lambda + \lambda^2)^3}{\lambda^2 (1 - \lambda)^2},$$
where $\lambda = k^2$. However, when the discriminant $\Delta$ is negative, $J(\tau)$ changes into
$$J' = -\frac{(1 - 16\lambda + 16\lambda^2)^3}{108\lambda(1 - \lambda)}.$$
Furthermore, it can be shown that
$$J(2\tau) = \frac{(16 - 16\lambda + \lambda^2)^3}{108\lambda^4 (1 - \lambda)}.$$
Incidentally, the right-hand side is the normalized $j$-invariant of the elliptic curve
$$E_1 : y^2 = (1 - t^2)(t^2 - \lambda'), \quad \lambda' = (1 - \lambda).$$
Moreover, we have
$$J\bigg(\frac{\tau}{2}\bigg) = \frac{(1 + 14\lambda + \lambda^2)^3}{108\lambda (1 - \lambda)^4},$$
where the right-hand side is the normalized $j$-invariant of
$$E_2 : y^2 = (1 - t^2)(1 - \lambda t^2).$$
On the other hand, $J'$ also happens to be the normalized $j$-invariant of the elliptic curve
$$E_3 : y^2 = (1 - t^2)(\lambda' + \lambda t^2).$$
This raises the question: Does $J'$ equal $J(r(\tau))$, where $r(\tau)$ is some simple rational function of $\tau$?

**Edit**: It appears that
$$J' = J\bigg(\frac{\tau + 1}{2}\bigg).$$
I have a proof, but this margin is too small to contain it.